# Duplicate input's value when clicked to button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a two similar forms with input "Quantity" and buttons "-", "+".

I need to duplicate input's value to second form and back.

For example: When I'm click to "+" in first form it will be incremented.

I need to in the second form was the same value.

```
<div class="quantity">
    <input class="subtraction" name="sub" type="button" value="-">
    <input type="number" step="1" name="qty" value="1"  class="input-text qty text panel-quantity" size="4"  />
    <input class="addition" name="add" type="button" value="+">
</div>
<div class="quantity">
    <input class="subtraction" name="sub" type="button" value="-">
    <input type="number" step="1" name="qty" value="1"  class="input-text qty text panel-quantity" size="4"/>
    <input class="addition" name="add" type="button" value="+">
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('.quantity').on('click', '.addition, .subtraction', function() {
        var quantityPanel = $('.panel-quantity');
        var quantity = $(this).closest('.quantity').find('input.qty');
        var currentValue = parseInt(quantity.val());
        var maxValue = parseInt(quantity.attr('max'));
        var minValue = parseInt(quantity.attr('min'));

        if($(this).is('.addition')) {
            if(maxValue && (currentValue >= maxValue)){
                quantity.val(maxValue);
            } else {
                quantity.val((currentValue + 1));
            }
        } else {
            if (minValue && (currentValue <= minValue)) {
                quantity.val(minValue);
            } else if(currentValue > 0) {
                quantity.val((currentValue - 1));
            }
        }
        quantity.trigger('change');
    });
});
```

I think that I can just set the same name for the INPUT, so that they work the same way.

Thanks

It's my example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AWK9S/747/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `$('input.qty').not(quantity).val(quantity.val());` before triggering change in the input box. and also you have add `$('input.qty').not(this).val($(this).val());` in onchange listener of `input.qty`

```js
$(function(){
 $('.quantity').on('click', '.addition, .subtraction', function() {
  var quantityPanel = $('.panel-quantity');
  var quantity = $(this).closest('.quantity').find('input.qty');
  var currentValue = parseInt(quantity.val());
  var maxValue = parseInt(quantity.attr('max'));
  var minValue = parseInt(quantity.attr('min'));

  if($(this).is('.addition')) {
   if(maxValue && (currentValue >= maxValue)){
    quantity.val(maxValue);
   } else {
    quantity.val((currentValue + 1));
   }
  } else {
   if (minValue && (currentValue <= minValue)) {
    quantity.val(minValue);
   } else if(currentValue > 0) {
    quantity.val((currentValue - 1));
   }
  }
    $('input.qty').not(quantity).val(quantity.val());
  quantity.trigger('change');
 });
  
 $('input.qty').on('change', function() {
      $('input.qty').not(this).val($(this).val());
      });
 $('input.qty').on('keyup', function() {
      $('input.qty').not(this).val($(this).val());
      });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quantity">
<input class="subtraction" name="sub" type="button" value="-">
 <input type="number" step="1" name="qty" value="1"  class="input-text qty text panel-quantity" size="4"  />
 <input class="addition" name="add" type="button" value="+">
</div>
<div class="quantity">
  <input class="subtraction" name="sub" type="button" value="-">
  <input type="number" step="1" name="qty" value="1"  class="input-text qty text panel-quantity" size="4"/>
  <input class="addition" name="add" type="button" value="+">
  </div>
```

Comment: You are Welcome mate